# Calculating Angles at Vertices

Tags: geometry

[image]

This is quite a tricky question and I can't answer it.

Comment: chasing the angles and using triangle angle sum yields nothing?

Comment: Make believe the vertices lie on a circle, and use the theorem that says that the angle subtended by a chord at a point on the circle is half the angle subtended by that chord at the center. Or type $$\rm sum\ of\ the\ angles\ of\ a\ star$$ into Google and see what comes up.

Comment: Nice question! Playing with GeoGebra confirms that the answer is 180 degrees, however.

Comment: Any thoughts on the two answers that have been posted, user108104?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved it and can prove the sum is 180 degrees.

Let's mark the vertices clockwise, from A to G. I will refer to `A, B .. G` as angles of the 'star'.

We form and take as example `AED` triangle; we know the sum of all angles is 180. Thus `A + ADE + DEA = A + E + BED + EDG + D = 180`  ( 1 ).

Let be `M` the point of intersection between `BE` and `GD`. In `EMD` triangle, we have angle `EMD = 180 - BED - EDG` ( 2 ).

From ( 1 ) and ( 2 ) => `A + E + D = EMD` ( 3 ). (similar procedure here for others)

Let be `N` the point of intersection between `AD` and `FC`. Let be `P` the point of intersection between `AE` and `FC`. In `ANP` triangle we have sum of all angles: `A + APN + ANP = 180` ( 4 ).

But actually, `ANP = DNC`. `DNC = G + D + C` as shown above in similar procedure as ( 3 ). The same: `APN = FPE = F + B + E`.

If we put all things together, formula ( 4 ) becomes `A + B + C + D + E + F = 180` (Q.E.D)

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that the external vertices of your star are the vertices of a regular heptagon (changing "not too much" the position of one vertex does not affect the sum of the angles), hence any angle equals $\frac{\pi}{7}$ by considering the circumscribed circle. This gives that the original angles sum up to $\pi$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a variation on the proof by @Cristi.

We start the same way; label the vertices clockwise, A to G, and we look at triangle ADE, whose angles sum to $\pi$ (measuring angles in radians, of course).

There are 7 triangles like ADE (the others are BEF, CFG, DGA, EAB, FBC, and GCD), so adding up all their angles gives $7\pi$.

But adding up all their angles also adds up all the angles of the heptagon ABCDEFG, but counting the angles of the star 3 times each. So, $$7\pi={\rm sum\ of\ angles\ of\ heptagon\ plus\ twice\ sum\ of\ angles\ of\ star}$$ Now the angles of the heptagon sum to $5\pi$ (the angles of any convex $n$-gon sum to $(n-2)\pi$), so $$7\pi=5\pi{\rm \ plus\ twice\ sum\ of\ angles\ of\ star}$$ so the angles of the star add up to $\pi$.